# Google Suite App Script Email Sending Limit

Tags: email, google-apps-script, smtp, gmail, google-workspace

I signed up for a google suite free trial and chose to make a domain name on the spot upon signing up for the free trial.

The free trial has a 500 emails per day sending limit using app script according to sites as oppose to consumer gmail accounts which can only send 100 emails per day.

What I did is make a simple script just to check if it could send 150 emails to make sure it is still within bound.
ex.

```
myfunction(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(//my email, "Iteration", i);
}
```

But it didn't work and made an error about sending limits. I tried sending 100 emails and it worked. So basically, my sending limit didn't upgrade to 500.

I consulted with the contact support and it told me to "check with the smtp reference of the script."

I didn't do any modifications to the admin settings or anything. I just literally signed up for the gsuite so that I can send more than 100 emails using appscript for small scale business functions.

Unfortunately I didn't know what the google support meant. Can someone give a resolution to this issue? Or enlighten me with what the contact support mean about smtp reference.

Comment: Have you tried sending 110? 105? Also, is your script using the **Gmail Service** or the **Mail Service**?

Comment: @AntoineColson
Yes. I did. My sending still cuts off after the the 100th iteration in the script. I use gmail service.

Comment: Recipients per message sent via (...) the Gmail API (...) : [100](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852). I know you are sending 100 messages with 1 recipient, but that could be it. In other words, chances are you can keep on sending emails manually after your script already sent 100 (could you try that please?). A workaround would be to send messages to [groups](https://support.google.com/a/answer/66338) instead. Also do make sure you try the [Mail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/) using `MailApp`, maybe that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a common mistake. People always think that by just signing up for a G Suite account they will be able to send more than 100 messages. As explained in the Scripts quotas article https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas you can email 1,500 per day if you have a paid G Suite account but not in free trial. If you want to be able to send more than 100 emails per day via GAS, you must end the G Suite free trial, and then your account must be billed for at least USD 30 (or the same amount in your currency). This is also explained at https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

*** If you want to increase your limits sooner, you can end your free trial and pay the amount now. For instructions, see Make a manual payment. It can take up to 48 hours to upgrade the limits after you submit the payment.   ***

Comment: I did think of that. However, why would Google promote that in free trial, you can send up to 500 messages? I did see somewhere within google's pages a caveat that the sending limit of 500 messages a day are given to particular types of gsuite trials. But I never saw any specifications. Could it be for business / enterprise trials? (Since they offer basic, business and enterprise - with basic being the cheapest among the 3)

Comment: The 500 messages limit that you are referring to is not for Google Apps Scripts but for the messages sent from the Gmail UI or via the Gmail SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com). It is a total different limit. It doesn't matter which G Suite Edition you sign up for, all of them have the same limits in place.

Comment: Would you happen to know what is the limit in calling the sendEmail function through app script then if it's different? Thank you

Comment: Please read the quotas article I provided. Every time you call the function it is like if you are sending a message. The limit is 100 per a 24 hours period. If you have a Paid GSuite Edition, it will be 1500 per day.

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily check your daily remaining quota in google app script. You can use the following code to get that.

```
var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
```